# how to use json in django

Tags: json, django

```
{ "symbol": "GOLD", "rates": [{ "time": "2023.08.02 09:00:00", "open": 1948.75000, "high": 1950.30000, "low": 1947.92000, "close": 1949.57000, "tick_volume": 3342, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 08:00:00", "open": 1946.28000, "high": 1949.90000, "low": 1946.27000, "close": 1948.78000, "tick_volume": 6574, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 07:00:00", "open": 1949.27000, "high": 1949.28000, "low": 1945.18000, "close": 1946.29000, "tick_volume": 3716, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 06:00:00", "open": 1948.18000, "high": 1949.44000, "low": 1946.58000, "close": 1949.27000, "tick_volume": 4494, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 05:00:00", "open": 1947.54000, "high": 1949.80000, "low": 1947.03000, "close": 1948.19000, "tick_volume": 6357, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 04:00:00", "open": 1949.14000, "high": 1949.79000, "low": 1947.58000, "close": 1947.60000, "tick_volume": 6730, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 03:00:00", "open": 1952.12000, "high": 1952.35000, "low": 1948.27000, "close": 1949.17000, "tick_volume": 5801, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 02:00:00", "open": 1951.14000, "high": 1952.80000, "low": 1950.44000, "close": 1952.10000, "tick_volume": 3464, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.02 01:00:00", "open": 1947.38000, "high": 1951.78000, "low": 1945.56000, "close": 1951.08000, "tick_volume": 5473, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 },{ "time": "2023.08.01 23:00:00", "open": 1944.36000, "high": 1944.82000, "low": 1943.97000, "close": 1944.24000, "tick_volume": 1335, "spread": 0, "real_volume": 0 } ] }
```

This is the data I sent to the background, I named it data and copied the above data to the json parser on the web page to get the correct result. Here's my background code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def receive_quotes(request):
    src = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    print(src)

    try:
        json_data = json.loads(src)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print("Error decoding JSON:", e)

    print(json_data)

    print("**************************************")

    symbol = json_data['symbol']

    print(symbol)
```

However, after loads sent the data, I was puzzled by Error decoding JSON: Extra data: line 1 column 1694 (char 1693) in my loads

I put the above data into the online json parser for parsing, and the result display format is fine
After that, to test it, I wrote a simple test:

```
import json

data=''（这里就是上面发送的数据）
print(data)
data_type=type(data)
data_type_str=str(data_type)
print('The type of data is:'+data_type_str)
print("**************************************")
json_data=json.loads(data)
json_data_type=type(json_data)
json_data_type_str=str(json_data_type)
print('The type of json_data is:'+json_data_type_str)
symbol=json_data['symbol']

print(symbol)
```

Results found that the above code can correctly output symbol value is "GOLD", I would like to ask you master master high master, what is the cause of this, and how to solve?

Comment: you need `json.loads` for loads string or bytes. while your `src` is as `dict` format you didn't need loads that.  You can use `src['symbol']` to get symbol.

Comment: @Saeed What makes you think `src` is a dict?!

Comment: src is a plain text，I use function json.loads to let src to be a json object,I now know where the problem is, there is a \x00 at the end of the src text, which makes it impossible to parse successfully, delete it to solve the problem